# Appending a single row from multiple CSV files to another CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using python 3 and pandas. I have a folder of multiple CSV files where each contain stats on a given date for all the regions of a country. I have created another folder for CSV files I created for each of the regions, one named for each of the regions listed in the CSV files in the first folder. I want to append the appropriate row from each of the first set of files to their respective region file in the second folder.

[This shows a portion of a CSV file from first folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhjQU.jpg)

[This shows the CSV files I created in the second folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45eOX.jpg)

Here is the code I'm running after creating the new set of region named files in the second folder. I don't get any errors, but I don't get the results I'm looking for either, which is a CSV file for each region in the second folder containing the daily stats from each of the files in the first folder.

```
 for csvname in os.listdir("NewTables"):
    if csvname.endswith(".csv"):
        df1 = pd.read_csv("NewTables/"+ csvname)
        name1 = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        for file in os.listdir():
            if file.endswith(".csv"):
                df2 = pd.read_csv(file)
                D = df2[df2["denominazione_regione"] == name1 ]
                df1.append(D, ignore_index = True)
                df1.to_csv("NewTables/"+ csvname)
```

Here are a few lines from a CSV file in the first folder:

data,stato,codice_regione,denominazione_regione,lat,long,ricoverati_con_sintomi,terapia_intensiva,totale_ospedalizzati,isolamento_domiciliare,totale_positivi,variazione_totale_positivi,nuovi_positivi,dimessi_guariti,deceduti,totale_casi,tamponi,note_it,note_en
2020-02-24T18:00:00,ITA,13,Abruzzo,42.35122196,13.39843823,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,,
2020-02-24T18:00:00,ITA,17,Basilicata,40.63947052,15.80514834,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
2020-02-24T18:00:00,ITA,04,P.A. Bolzano,46.49933453,11.35662422,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,

Comment: A csv file is a **text** file. Please show a line from one of the input csv files as it would show in Notepad, vi or any other text editor, and also show what should be in the resulting files. As we cannot copy/paste from images, we cannot try to reproduce with relevant data...

Comment: I added some of the lines of one of the CSV files from the first folder that will be used to populate/append the files of the second folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use pandas here because there is little data processing and mainly file processing. So I would stick to the csv module.

I would look over the csv files in the first directory and process them one at a time. For each row I would just append it in the file with the relevant name in the second folder. I assume that the number of regions is reasonably small, so I would keep the files in second folder opened to save open/close time on each row.

The code could be:

```
import glob
import os.path
import csv

outfiles = {}   # cache the open files and the associated writer in 2nd folder
for csvname in glob.glob('*.csv'):     # loop over csv files from 1st folder
    with open(csvname) as fdin:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fdin)      # read the file as csv
        for row in rd:
            path = "NewTables/"+row['denominazione_regione']+'.csv'
            newfile = not os.path.exists(path)   # a new file?
            if row['denominazione_regione'] not in outfiles:
                fdout = open(path, 'a', newline='')  # not in cache: open it
                wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, rd.fieldnames)
                if newfile:
                    wr.writeheader()   # write header line only for new files
                outfiles[row['denominazione_regione']] = (wr, fdout) # cache
            wr = outfiles[row['denominazione_regione']][0]
            wr.writerow(row)           # write the row in the relevant file
for file in outfiles.values():        # close every outfile
    file[1].close()
```